# How to add a html element next to the cursor in contentEditable div. React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a component, which is returning a contentEditable div. Users can type a text inside the div. This div is quite similer to a textarea. I need to add a `<span></span>` tag to, where the cursor is exist at the moment by clicking on a button located outside the div.

```
class EditableDiv extends React.Component {

    addSpan() {
        // return a composed <span> tag
    }

    render() {
        return(
           <div contentEditable
               onInput={(event)=>{this.handleKeyPress(event)}}>
           </div>
           <button onClick={this.addSpan}></button>;
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the code to add a `<span></span>` after click on a button.

#### Edit

> Need to add the span inside the content editable div. next to the cursor.

I now handle the div `handleKeyPress()` event to set `this.state.divValue` and add `<span></span>` if :

- `this.state.divValue` is not empty
- `this.state.buttonPressed` is `true` (button pressed)

*Note : I don't know if you have already code your `<div contentEditable` component so I let the code as you given, just added the `value={divValue}` part*

```
class EditableDiv extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    // State
    this.state = {
      divValue: '',
      buttonPressed: false
    }
    // Bind
    this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.addSpan = this.addSpan.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyPress(e) {
    this.setState({ divValue: e.currentTarget.value });
  }

  addSpan() {
    this.setState({ buttonPressed: true });
  }

  render() {
    var divValue = this.state.divValue;

    if (this.state.buttonPressed && divValue) {
      divValue += <span></span>;
    }

    return(
       <div>
         <div contentEditable
           onInput={(event)=>{this.handleKeyPress(event)}}
           value={divValue}>
         </div>
         <button onClick={this.addSpan}></button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Need to add the span inside the content editable div. next to the cursor.

Comment: What if the user bring the cursor to the middle of the content and click on the button. Will the <span> tag be inserted to that place.